# Member objects, references and shared_ptr

Tags: c++

So, I've found myself doing this a lot, and wonder if it's correct practice (this probably won't compile - I'm writing this on my phone):

```
class Shared
{
private:
    int _x;
public:
    void X(int newValue) { _x = newValue; } 
    int X() { return _x; } 

    Shared(void) : _x(0)
    {
    }
};

class Owner
{
private:
    shared_ptr<Shared> _shared;

public:
    const Shared& Shared() const
    {
        return *_shared;
    }

    void Shared(const Shared& newValue)
    {
        _shared.reset(&newValue);
    }

    void DoSomethingWithShared()
    {
        /// yeah, this could be cleaner, not the point!
        _shared.X(_shared.X() + 1);
    }

};

void CreateStuff(Owner& a, Owner &b)
{
    Shared s;

    a.Shared(s);
    b.Shared(s);

}




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Owner a;
    Owner b;
    CreateStuff(a,b);

    a.DoSomethingWithShared();
    b.DoSomethingWithShared();
    ///...



    /// "Shared" instance created in CreateStuff() hopefully lives until here...

}
```

The idea is that multiple instances of `Owner` need a shared resource of type `Shared`.

- Is `CreateStuff()` an error? (ie, does `s` go out of scope, leaving `a` and `b` with invalid pointers to a destroyed object? (Am I returning the address of a temporary in a roundabout way?)
- Are there any other scope/GC issues I'm not seeing?
- Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Note that this is a pure C++ question. Nothing C++11 or VS specific. Changed the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateStuff` is definitively wrong. You're (eventually) passing a pointer to a local variable into the `shared_ptr`s, which outlive that variable. Once it goes out of scope, you'll have two dangling pointers inside those `_shared`s.

Since you're using smart pointers, why not dynamically allocate that `Shared` on the heap, and let the smart pointers worry about deleting it when they're done?

```
void CreateStuff(Owner& a, Owner &b)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Shared> s(new Shared);

    a.Shared(s);  // have that Shared() modified to take the shared_ptr,
    b.Shared(s);  // of course
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that, in the `::Shared()` setter, calling `shared_ptr::reset()` makes them belong to the same ownership group. Is that correct?

Comment: Oh, that's a point I actually missed - when passing the raw pointer, the two `shared_ptr`s don't know about each other. As soon as one goes out of scope, it will try to delete the object. Had it been possible, it would have left the other with a dangling pointer. Changing the arguments to a `shared_ptr`, as I've already suggested, will fix this as well.

Comment: `void Shared(std::shared_ptr<Shared> newValue) { _shared = std::move(newValue); }` It's best to take `newValue` by value, since it will also implicitly accept `std::unique_ptr<Shared>`.